# What font does JSFiddle's website use

Tags: fonts

Recently JSFiddle's website has revamped the layout and design.

Does anyone know what font is used in JSFiddle? I've tried to use inspect element to get the font family, but I couldn't found the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering what font family they using to display *code* then it's:

```
   font-family
     'Fira Mono',
     Monaco,
     'Andale Mono',
     'Lucida Console',
     'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono',
     'Courier New',
     Courier,
     monospace
```

Font family for *website menus* is:

```
   font-family
     Lato,
     Helvetica,
     Arial,
     FreeSans,
     Verdana,
     Tahoma,
     'Lucida Sans',
     'Lucida Sans Unicode',
     'Luxi Sans',
     sans-serif
```

Right click on element, in the element inspector on the right pane (if element inspector is docked on the bottom side of the screen) select 'Computed' tab, and you'll see font-family.